# Train a model subject to max error

Tags: loss-functions, importance-sampling, constrained-optimization

I would like to train a neural network by minimizing a loss over samples (as usual), but doing so in a way that the maximum error is bounded.

What options do I have? Some that come to mind are:

- preferential sampling
- loss modification (e.g. minimize loss*loss instead of loss, which is a softening of $L_\infty$)

Are there other methods? How to best (or easily) implement these ways?

Comment: Why do you want to bound max error? It’s nearly impossible to bound max error, because you ask for bound to hold for arbitrary, unseen data.

Comment: Because if the error is large I lose money. Am I wrong if I assume a model with limited max training error will likely have limited max error when deployed? The question, however, was targeting the training set fitting only.

Comment: If the distribution of training data is exactly like the prediction time data. The problem is that you are concerned with the tails of the distribution, it’s much easier to have guarantees on quantiles vs maximum.